# how to add vertical spacing after a breakpoint in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

when I surpass the breakpoint i need to add some vertical spacing but I don't know how to add it to the rows, I've tried to insert `my-md-5`  into the col class but it doesn't change

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="fauna" class="p-5 bg-secondary text-light">
    <div class="text-center pb-2">
      <h3 class="text-dark">La fauna del garda</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-lg my-2">
      <div class="row gx-5">
        <div class="col-md text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Pesci</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
              <h5>Il lago possiede una grande varietà di pesci, fra i più comuni abbiamo l'alosa, il luccio e il lavarello</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md  text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Volatili</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
              <h5>Tuttavia il Garda all'interno del suo ecosistema include anche volatili, quali i gabbiani, folaghe, germani reali e nei dintorni delle spiagge, oltre a tordi, fringuelli, merli, pettirossi, cinciallegre e capinere</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md  text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Mammiferi</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
              <h5>Invece nei dintorni del lago si trovano una moltitudine di animali selvatici molto vari tra i quali stambecchi e numerosi camosci e nelle zone boschive lepri, scoiattoli, donnole, volpi e marmotte</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#gap) in this case `gap-3` property like that:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>


  <section id="fauna" class="p-5 bg-secondary text-light">
    <div class="text-center pb-2">
      <h3 class="text-dark">La fauna del garda</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-lg my-2">
      <div class="row gx-5 gap-3">
        <div class="col-md text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Pesci</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
                <h5>Il lago possiede una grande varietà di pesci, fra i più comuni abbiamo l'alosa, il luccio e il lavarello</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md  text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Volatili</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
                <h5>Tuttavia il Garda all'interno del suo ecosistema include anche volatili, quali i gabbiani, folaghe, germani reali e nei dintorni delle spiagge, oltre a tordi, fringuelli, merli, pettirossi, cinciallegre e capinere</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md  text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Mammiferi</h3>
              <p class="card-text">
                <h5>Invece nei dintorni del lago si trovano una moltitudine di animali selvatici molto vari tra i quali stambecchi e numerosi camosci e nelle zone boschive lepri, scoiattoli, donnole, volpi e marmotte</h5>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome ;-)  Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it works like you want:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="fauna" class="p-5 bg-secondary text-light">
  <div class="text-center pb-2">
    <h3 class="text-dark">La fauna del garda</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-lg my-2">

    <div class="container-lg my-2">

      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Pesci</h3>
              <p class="card-text h5">Il lago possiede una grande varietà di pesci, fra i più comuni abbiamo l'alosa, il luccio e il lavarello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Volatili</h3>
              <p class="card-text h5">Tuttavia il Garda all'interno del suo ecosistema include anche volatili, quali i gabbiani, folaghe, germani reali e nei dintorni delle spiagge, oltre a tordi, fringuelli, merli, pettirossi, cinciallegre e capinere</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <div class="card bg-dark h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title text-warning">Mammiferi</h3>
              <p class="card-text h5">Invece nei dintorni del lago si trovano una moltitudine di animali selvatici molto vari tra i quali stambecchi e numerosi camosci e nelle zone boschive lepri, scoiattoli, donnole, volpi e marmotte</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div </div>
</section>
```

You can also watch at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dryant/pen/xxXYExJ?editors=1000)

I hope I've helped